# implementing NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm having some problems implementing `NSFetchedResultsController` for something very simple. I'm just trying to learn how it works. All I want to do is display the `firstName` attribute of `Person` entities in a table view.

As far as I know I've implemented all the methods required but nothing is showing up in the table view. The method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method isn't even being called.

Here is my code:

```
@implementation MyTableViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

-(NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController
{

    if (!_fetchedResultsController)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];    
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    NSError *error = nil;

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = person.firstName;
    return cell;
}
```

any help would be hugely appreciated! many thanks, Alex

Comment: Have you properly overridden `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` UITableViewDataSource method?

Comment: Are you sure you have objects in your database? Try logging `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects`. Take a look at the "Master-Detail Application" project template in Xcode 4.2 for reference (see [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657205/core-data-and-uitableview-practices-questions/8658204#8658204)).

Comment: Is the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method getting called? If so, do you get a valid `Person` object via fetchedResultsController?

Comment: @LordTwaroog that method only needs to be overwritten if you have more than 1 section.

Comment: Also - what about moving the performFetch from viewDidAppear to viewWillAppear?

Comment: Did you forget to connect the datasource of the tableview to your viewController? Put some NSLog into `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to check that at least this method is called.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone for all the responses. All that was needed as it turns out was to move the performFetch method to viewWillAppear from viewDidAppear. Why does this make a difference though?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:]` and implement its `delegate`

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

See more at: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Answer (score -1):

Try getting your NSString from your Person object and via the code here:

`NSString *firstName = ((Person *)[personArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).firstName;`

Mind you, my suggested line is assuming that you output your NSFetchRequest to a NS(Mutable)Array called personArray.

Hopefully that helps, otherwise let me know.